# Can i accomplish this using streams Java 8?

Tags: java, stream

Can I use streams to make this same block of code? Is it more efficient that way?
Here is my code:

```
 public class Indexer {

    public static List<Integer> getIndexes(String word, char letter) {
        List<Integer> wordIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

        if (word.indexOf(letter) >= 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (word.charAt(i) == letter) {
                    wordIndexes.add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return wordIndexes;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is achievable with the use of the IntStream:

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, word.length())
                                .filter(i -> String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).equals(letter))
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As @Locke mentioned, as here the string is being processed, `char` by `char`, converting both the operands for the equality check to `char` is more appropriate. This can be achieved by defining letter as `char letter = '?';` and then the filter clause would be something like that:

```
.filter(i -> word.charAt(i) == letter)
```

Comment: This could be further improved by making `letter` a `char` and using `.filter(i -> word.charAt(i) == letter)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As for the second question ("Is it more efficient that way?"),  I would also like to point out, that even though streams may be more readable, a plain-old for loop will most likely have the best performance.

```java
List<Integer> wordIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
String word = "ajborefbla";
char letter = 'b';

for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == letter) {
        wordIndexes.add(i);
    }
}
```